# Obtaining both the name and phone number from a Google People API search

Tags: python, google-api, google-people-api

I'm using the Google People API in Python to query my Google Contacts list.  I can get this feature to work, but one specific operation does not work.

```
results = service.people().connections().list(
    resourceName='people/me',
    pageSize=1,
    personFields='names,phoneNumbers').execute()
connections = results.get('connections', [])

for person in connections:
    data = person.get('names', [])
```

This works -- it gives me a list of names.  However, I want a list of names and phone numbers.  If I do this:

```
for person in connections:
    data = person.get('phoneNumbers', [])
```

This also works.  I get a list of phone numbers.  However, if I try to get both, I get no results:

```
for person in connections:
    data = person.get('names,phoneNumbers', [])
```

According to my interpretation of the People API docs (https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get), this should work.  Instead, I just get nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `person.get()` you are **not** calling the `v1/people/get` endpoint, you're just getting a value from a **dictionary**.

The previous call to `service.people().connections()....execute()` already gets all the information from the API and puts it in a list of dictionaries.

Then when you iterate over `connections` you get a dictionary named `person` which holds two keys `names` and `phoneNumbers`.
Your code is trying to get a key with the name of `names,phoneNumbers` which doesn't exist.

Not sure how you're using `data` or what type are you expecting it to be, but to have `data` contain both name and phones simply do:

```
data = person
```

or just use `person` directly in the rest of your code.

Answer (score 1):

As @marmor has said, the error lies in how you are accessing the content of the response. The method `dict.get()` does refuse two keys at the same time.
Here are two different approaches that you can use.

```py
# Calling them separately
personName = person.get('names', [])
personPhone = person.get('phoneNumbers',[])
# Calling them together using list compression
keys = ["names","phoneNumbers"]
data = [person.get(key) for key in keys]
```

You should refer to [people().connections().list()](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/people_v1.people.connections.html#list) to better understand the response format. In this case, it is a resource of type [Person](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#Person)

As another possible approximation is, getting a list of names and their phone numbers and store them in a dictionary:

###### Code sample

```py
def getNameAndPhones():
  service = people_service()
  results = service.people().connections().list(
    resourceName= "people/me",                                
    personFields='names,phoneNumbers').execute()              
  person_dict = {}           
  for per in  results['connections']:                         
    try:
      name =  per['names'][0]['displayName'] 
      # As the response is an array
      # we need to do some list comprehension
      phoneNumbers = [x['value'] for x in per['phoneNumbers']]         
      person_dict[name] = phoneNumber
    except : 
      name =  per['names'][0]['displayName']         
      person_dict[name] = "No phone Number"

  print(person_dict)
  return person_dict
```

###### Response

```json
{
   "Eco":["00112233"],
   "Maxim maxim":"No phone Number",
   "dummy super":[
      "123123123",
      "12312309812390"
   ]
}
```

###### Documentation

- [Python API Library v1](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/people_v1.html)
- [People API](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest)